# WebSocket is always pending cause page to stuck

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

My front end project is using Vue framework with vue-router to control page route.
In router.js file I declare a new Router variable as:

```
const router =  new Router({
  routes: [
      {
          path:'/',
          name:'loginComponent',
          component:loginComponent,
      },
      {
          path: '/home',
          name: 'home',
          component: home,
      },
  ]
});
```

However, When app runs at route part (this.$router.push('/home');), it sucks forever...
Chrome console shows that a file called WebSocket is always pending, which is the main cause I think. 
How can I solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: The console log would probably be useful :)

Comment: Hey! Please add the part where you setup websockets in your app and the console log of your browser. Your router.js file looks good and doesnt seem to be the issue here.